# Create new shell instance within shell script

Tags: bash, docker, shell, containers

I have two scripts that I would like to execute.

Script 1: A script that executes docker run (needs to stay active because if it is closed the docker container stops running)

Script 2: A script that runs docker exec and gets into the docker shell

Problem:
I need to run script 1 and script 2 in separate shells because script 1 needs to stay active and cannot be closed.

1. Separating the scripts into two separate files and then running both scripts from one file
2. sh script1.sh & sh script2.sh

Comment: Why do you need to create this? It sounds like a bad technical solution. What is your real problem here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not just `docker run --detach …`?

Comment: You also shouldn't routinely need `docker exec`.  It's very useful, but I'd normally expect the `docker run` step to do all of the setup required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it as one big script.
When executing/running the docker container use the `--detach` or `-d` flag.
This ensures, that the container does not stay active in the terminal but moves into the background (it keeps running!).

The docker command would look something like
`docker run -d ...`